# ARR keeps asking for authentication

Tags: iis, arr

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 server with IIS and ARR installed.

I have created a server farm for a website hosted inside my network (I only have 1 public IP available) but when I try to access this site externally I keep getting authentication requests.

The first request states its for "Digest" but Digest is not installed and if I cancel that, a normal plain authentication request pops up, if I cancel that too then the site just shows a blank page.

I have tried authenticating both requests using a variety of credentials including my domain admin.

This site runs from a Linux VM and I have never seen this issue before when using ARR to reverse proxy a site from Linux.

Comment: Do you have an AD FS server setup separately for the ARR to use against for authentication?